# Wicket call method after pressing enter

Tags: java, javascript, wicket, panel, keylistener

In my Wicket application I would like to call a method by clicking on a button. I googled and found some solutions for wicket forms, but no easy solutions for panels without a form. Is there a easy way to implement a key listener in Wicket, that works a bit like the Java Swing  mouselistener interface?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can catch this event with the following code:

```
$(document).keypress(function(e){
    if(e.which == 13) {
        //call server-side function here
        console.log('You pressed enter!');
    }
})
```

[Here](https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/calling-wicket-from-javascript.html) you can read how can you make calls from JS to wicket.